How to use the condition for multiple columns in Pandas?
I want to replace values in columns from P1-6 to P1-95 with values from column family if the value in a particular column > 0. Here is the part of my input df te_matrix:
     family   P1-6  P1-12  P1-22  P1-25  P1-26  P1-28  P1-88  P1-89  P1-90  P1-92  P1-93  P1-95
 Tourist|20  0.712  0.587  0.838  0.675  0.771  0.952  0.746  0.678  0.603  0.728  0.680  0.759
Stowaway|36  0.740  0.809  0.796  0.699  1.000  0.865  0.814  0.888  0.705  0.758  0.759  0.866
 Stowaway|4  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.880  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000

I write it for one column, P1-6:
te_matrix['P1-6'] = te_matrix.apply(lambda row: row['family'] if row['P1-6'] > 0 else row['P1-6'], axis=1)

and works well:
     family         P1-6  P1-12  P1-22  P1-25  P1-26  P1-28  P1-88  P1-89  P1-90  P1-92  P1-93  P1-95
 Tourist|20   Tourist|20  0.587  0.838  0.675  0.771  0.952  0.746  0.678  0.603  0.728  0.680  0.759
Stowaway|36  Stowaway|36  0.809  0.796  0.699  1.000  0.865  0.814  0.888  0.705  0.758  0.759  0.866
 Stowaway|4        0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.880  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000

but how to use it for all desired columns without writing almost the same code line by line?
I guess to start with:
cols = te_matrix.filter(like='P1-').columns but how to apply it to the previous code?

Can you [edit] your question to provide the output of te_matrix.to_dict('tight') for reproduciblity?

@mozway I just edited to fix the alignment, is that what you wanted? Or is it also that the 0.000 in the result P1-6 should be 0.0 if it's a float and the column is object?

@wjandrea thanks, indeed it would still be important that OP provides this output to know the dtypes of the data

Don't use apply, it's not needed here really inefficient.
Go with boolean indexing:
df.loc[df['P1-6'].gt(0), 'P1-6'] = df['family']

Output:
        family         P1-6  P1-12  P1-22  P1-25  P1-26  P1-28  P1-88  P1-89  P1-90  P1-92  P1-93  P1-95
0   Tourist|20   Tourist|20  0.587  0.838  0.675  0.771  0.952  0.746  0.678  0.603  0.728  0.680  0.759
1  Stowaway|36  Stowaway|36  0.809  0.796  0.699  1.000  0.865  0.814  0.888  0.705  0.758  0.759  0.866
2   Stowaway|4          0.0  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.880  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000

If you want to update several columns at once, go with mask:
cols = df.filter(like='P1-').columns

df[cols] = df[cols].mask(df[cols].gt(0), df['family'], axis=0)

Or, if you're unsure if the input columns only contain numbers, with help of pd.to_numeric:
cols = df.filter(like='P1-').columns

df[cols] = df[cols].mask(df[cols].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').gt(0),
                         df['family'], axis=0)

Output:
        family         P1-6        P1-12        P1-22        P1-25        P1-26        P1-28        P1-88        P1-89        P1-90        P1-92        P1-93        P1-95
0   Tourist|20   Tourist|20   Tourist|20   Tourist|20   Tourist|20   Tourist|20   Tourist|20   Tourist|20   Tourist|20   Tourist|20   Tourist|20   Tourist|20   Tourist|20
1  Stowaway|36  Stowaway|36  Stowaway|36  Stowaway|36  Stowaway|36  Stowaway|36  Stowaway|36  Stowaway|36  Stowaway|36  Stowaway|36  Stowaway|36  Stowaway|36  Stowaway|36
2   Stowaway|4          0.0          0.0          0.0          0.0          0.0          0.0   Stowaway|4          0.0          0.0          0.0          0.0          0.0


I think you are on the right way using cols = te_matrix.filter(like='P1-').columns. After that apply the condition to each specified column.
Code:
for col in cols:
    te_matrix[col] = te_matrix.apply(lambda row: row['family'] if row[col] > 0 else row[col], axis=1)

Output:
      family         P1-6        P1-12        P1-22        P1-25  \
0   Tourist|20   Tourist|20   Tourist|20   Tourist|20   Tourist|20   
1  Stowaway|36  Stowaway|36  Stowaway|36  Stowaway|36  Stowaway|36   
2   Stowaway|4          0.0          0.0          0.0          0.0   

         P1-26        P1-28        P1-88        P1-89        P1-90  \
0   Tourist|20   Tourist|20   Tourist|20   Tourist|20   Tourist|20   
1  Stowaway|36  Stowaway|36  Stowaway|36  Stowaway|36  Stowaway|36   
2          0.0          0.0   Stowaway|4          0.0          0.0   

         P1-92        P1-93        P1-95  
0   Tourist|20   Tourist|20   Tourist|20  
1  Stowaway|36  Stowaway|36  Stowaway|36  
2          0.0          0.0          0.0  


It raised me the TypeError:   File "/home/emoranska/Pulpit/burak/P1_P4/calculations.py", line 30, in <lambda>     te_matrix[col] = te_matrix.apply(lambda row: row['family'] if row[col] > 0 else row[col], axis=1) TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int' 

Have you tried te_matrix[cols] = te_matrix[cols].astype(float)?

Yes, the same error was raised..

@emor You need to undo your .apply() before you run this code. Your code changes the dtype of P1-6 from numeric to object (which, BTW, is kind of weird).

@wjandrea, I checked it as you wrote and it is weird indeed.. Why does it work like that?

@emor Oh I mean, it's weird that you're changing column dtypes. Why are you doing that?

Another way of doing
cols = te_matrix.filter(like='P1-').columns

can be
for col in te_matrix.columns:
    if col.startswith("P1-"):
        do_something()

